# ICallbackEventHandler, RaiseCallbackEvent not firing

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, ajax

I have the following Javascript:

```
        function processText(n)
        {                
            CallServer("1" + n.id + "&" + n.value, "");
        }

        function ReceiveServerData(arg, context)
        {
            alert(arg);
        }
```

With this for my code-behind:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScriptManager cm = Page.ClientScript;
        String cbRef = cm.GetCallbackEventReference(this, "arg", "ReceiveServerData", "context");

        String callbackscript = "function CallServer(arg, context) {" + cbRef + "; }";
        cm.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "CallServer", callbackscript, true);

        if (Request.QueryString["stationID"] != null)
        {
            isIndividual = true;
            stationID = Request.QueryString["stationID"];

            EncodeDecode objServers = new EncodeDecode(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"));

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                List<IServerConfig> serverConfig = objServers.GetServerConfiguration(stationID);
                Session["ServerConfig"] = serverConfig;
                Session["dctPropertyControls"] = new Dictionary<string, PropertyObj>();
            }

            BindDynamicControls(Session["ServerConfig"] as List<IServerConfig>);
        }
    }

    public void RaiseCallbackEvent(String eventArgument)
    {
        int iTyped = int.Parse(eventArgument.Substring(0, 1).ToString());

        if (iTyped != 0) //Process Text Fields
        {
            string controlName = eventArgument.Substring(1, eventArgument.IndexOf("&")).ToString();
            string controlValue = eventArgument.Substring(eventArgument.IndexOf("&")).ToString();
            //Txtid += -1;                

            Dictionary<string, PropertyObj> dctPropertyObj = Session["dctPropertyControls"] as Dictionary<string, PropertyObj>;
            PropertyObj propertyObj = dctPropertyObj[controlName];
            propertyObj.property.SetValue(propertyObj.owner, controlValue, null);                

            this.sGetData = "Done";
        }
    }

    public String GetCallbackResult()
    {
        return this.sGetData;
    }
```

processText gets fired and works, however RaiseCallbackEvent never fires. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, any sort of validation error will cause this, though the page will never tell you about it. In my case, I had two datalists on the page with the same id. I had to debug the javascript and read the xmlRequest to see the error.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if replying late but may help others..

`ValidationRequest="false"` at .aspx page may sort out this unidentified problem.